# Is arm64-v8a compatible with armeabi-v7a?

Tags: android, compatibility, abi

For my Android-app I'm using the ABI "x86" and "armeabi" right now.
The armeabi is used for all ARM-devices, including armv7a and arm64-v8a.

Now I would like to remove the "armeabi" and just continue with "x86" and "armeabi-v7a".

I haven't found any hint in the docs, that ARMv8 is also compatible with ARMv7 - can anyone confirm that my app will still work on devices running arm64-v8a, if I don't offer an armeabi but now an armeabi-v7a-library?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Many modern Android devices (i.e. Nexus 5x) have **AArch64** processors with **arm64-v8a** instruction set.  Both - `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a` - libraries run fine on these modern devices.  Therefore, we can assume the answer to your question to be 'YES'.

See this for a breakdown of ABI management on Android: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html

Comment: Though provided answer is lireally correct, starting August 1, 2019, apps published on Google Play need to support 64-bit architectures. That means that 
now you may receive warnings or errors when trying to upload/release apps via Google Play without providing 64-bit instruction sets for existing(already built) 32-bit libs.

Comment: so armeabi-v7a can be installed on arm64-v8a device ?