# Android : libopencv_java3.so not found for armeabi-v7a abi filter on aarch64 platform

Tags: android, opencv

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33317689/is-arm64-v8a-compatible-with-armeabi-v7a) and [this post](https://android.jlelse.eu/controlling-apk-size-when-using-native-libraries-45c6c0e5b70a) mention that the NDK builds with `armeabi-v7a` ABI filters would work for `aarch64` Android platforms as well, so we don't need to include `arm64-v8a` in the ABI filters list.

However, I faced the following problem on two `aarch64` platforms, a Lenovo Phab-P1770M and a Redmi 3S.

I am using opencv library in my project. However, when I add the following to my `app.module`

```
ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
```

I see that the built apk does not include `libopencv_java3.so` in the `lib/armeabi-v7a` and `lib/x86` folders. Calling `opencv` functions, obviously crashes as well with the error, `libopencv_java3.so`.

However, when I add `arm64-v8a` to the list above, `lib/arm64-v8a` folder is additionally created in the APK as well ( as expected). But the `libopencv_java3.so` library is present only in that directory and as expected, the module gets loaded properly on runtime.

So basically, I want to understand whether just using the ABI filter `armeabi-v7a` work for `aarch64` platform as well or not. Because the aforementioned two posts say that it should, but my experience does not show that.

Can anyone help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`armeabi-v7a` is 32-bit CUP architecture, usually it is compatible with 64-bit architecture as well. If you don't provide the proper dynamic library, i.e. the corresponding `arm64-v8a`, Installation manager will pick up the secondary ABI, i.e. the `armeabi-v7a` for your target phone.

But, why not always use the primary ABI for your app? As the primary ABI will give your app best performance.

You can get more details about abi from here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis