# What are the new build variant automatically created in my project after updating to latest AndroidStudio 3.3.0 : arm64-v8a, armeabi-V7a

Tags: android, x86, x86-64, arm64, android-productflavors

After updating android studio 3.3. my build variant are divided into four kind of flavour `product_flavour-arm64-V8a`, `product_flavour-aremabi-V7a`, `product_flavour-x86` and `product_flavour-x86_64`, which one should I use to install my build and what are the purpose of all these new build variant.

I searched it but didn't find much, my findings ended on [CPU Architectures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/cpu-architectures?tabs=macos)
[Is arm64-v8a compatible with armeabi-v7a?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33317689/is-arm64-v8a-compatible-with-armeabi-v7a), which didn't helped me much to understand. 
I also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33317689/is-arm64-v8a-compatible-with-armeabi-v7a)

Comment: What is unclear about the CPU architectures page? Different devices run with different CPUs, e.g. ARM, ARM64, Intel x86 or X86-64. These require different machine code, so you get different binaries.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: The point is that when one is distributing an app, one wants to build it for multiple architectures and include them all in the distributed APK. Which used to be automatic and now (it seems) is not.