# Xamarin: Does setting to 64bit works for 64 bit android devices?

Tags: android, xamarin, 64-bit

I just recently found out I have to configure my app to 64 bit in order to submit to play[image]

I found an answer of how to configure. I don't have 64 bit devices myself. Do I need to test the application on 64 bit in order to make sure it's running correctly?

If not, how do I tell which libraries are not running in 64 bit.

I have got 4 folders:

arm64-v8a   armeabi-v7a x86     x86_64

each folders has same files:

libe_sqlite3.so     libmono-profiler-log.so libxamarin-app.so
libmono-btls-shared.so  libmonodroid.so
libmono-native.so   libmonosgen-2.0.so

Comment: What do you get when you try: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#unzip-apks

Comment: I have added after unzip the apk file. I have edited the question for more details

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with Xamarin but do know they are 64-bit compliant.

As all folders `arm64-v8a` `armeabi-v7a` `x86` `x86_64` appear to have the same files I expect you not using any third-party Android libraries which use C/C++ code and the app is therefore 64-bit compliant.

I do recommend reading all of: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

You can try the Android SDK Emulator which as 64-bit device images.

I would expect though that at some point you should acquire a 64-bit device for testing, as a number of 'mid-range' devices are using 64-bit architecture.

As of late 2019, 32-bit apps have **NOT** be deprecated, and given the need for devices at low-end price points/non-Western countries, 32-bit apps will be around for some time.

Comment: Thanks. does the apk still visible by 64 bit devices in playStore

Comment: Yes, as Android mandates 32-bit support on 64-bit devices. So "for now" older 32-bit only apps in the Play Store are available to 64-bit devices. See: [Is arm64-v8a compatible with armeabi-v7a?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33317689/295004)