# UnsatisfiedLinkError : Is armeabi compiled library compatible with arm64-v8a?

Tags: android, arm

I have a `libfoo.so` library which I used it for architecture `armeabi` for my old Android system. Today I am building to new architecture `arm64-v8a`, I have configured correctly in gradle `abiFilters += 'arm64-v8a'`, and I unzip my apk, I can find my `libfoo.so` library in `myApp.apk/lib/arm64-v8a`. I don't have source code for this `libfoo.so` library, so I used back previous one which is built for `armeabi`. But I got the error as below:

`2020-11-17 20:56:23.039 13083-13556/? W/System.err: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/sg.com.aa.bb-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/sg.com.aa.bb-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/sg.com.aa.bb-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libfoo.so"`

As you can see this path `/data/app/sg.com.aa.bb-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a`, I am pretty sure my `libfoo.so` file is inside, but why it keep saying `couldn't find libfoo.so`?

I run `file` command on the file `libfoo.so`, it shows:

`ELF 32-bit LSB pie executable ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /system/, stripped`

There are people asked similar question before, `arm64-v8a` should be compatible with those 32 bit library, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33317689/is-arm64-v8a-compatible-with-armeabi-v7a). And [this](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html), it says `64-bit devices also support their 32-bit variants. Using arm64-v8a devices as an example, the device can also run armeabi and armeabi-v7a code. Note, however, that your application will perform much better on 64-bit devices if it targets arm64-v8a rather than relying on the device running the armeabi-v7a version of your application.`

In this case, could it be other possibilities that cause the `UnsatisfiedLinkError` above?

---

**Conclusion**:

I finally got what @Jake mean, I am kind of confused with what so-called "arm64-v8a support 32 bit too". Yes, it does support but provided it runs in 64 bit mode, and once an Android app start in 64 bit mode, it can't execute any 32 bit C library. So I have to find a way to force the app to run in 32 bit mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Some `armv8-a` cores don't have `aarch32` mode.
- `aarch32` functions can only be called on OS operating in `aarch32` mode.
- You cannot mix `aarch32` binaries with `aarch64` ones.
- An architecture isn't an ABI
- `aarch32` binaries only run on 32bit abi.