# Android Studio / arm64-v8a and armeabi-v7a

Tags: android, android-studio

I heard that arm64 works with libraries armeabi-v7a and starts everything normally. But I have .so files (jniLibs) there and I can’t compile them for arm64-v8a (the sources do not allow), tell me what needs to be written in the project to run on v8a apk with v7a?

```
   ndk {             
     abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"         
   }
```

Comment: as far as I can tell you put nothing more than you have, an app that only ships old 32bit arm libraries will still work on a 64bit device (https://stackoverflow.com/q/33317689/995891 or https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis#android-platform-abi-support). You can test on any android device from recent years

Comment: @zapl what if I try to install - it tells me that INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS, in turn I add the code: abiFilters: "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", the app just crashes

Comment: you can't claim to have arm64-v8a. What kind of device is that? Emulators maybe don't support 32bit mode but usually real devices do: https://github.com/rolandsmeenk/ARCore-devices/blob/master/arcore_devicelist.csv (see ABIs column)

Comment: @zapl android studio, Mac M1 chip, arm64-v8a emulator :(

Comment: Oh and some popular google pixel phones (7, 7a) seem to only support arm64 (also https://www.xda-developers.com/google-pixel-7-64-bit-only-apps/). You unfortunately can't compile 32bit code for 64 bit in many cases so maybe you can find alternatives to the library or code you're using. Porting code to 64 bit would mean facing issues like https://www.edn.com/accelerating-code-migration-from-arm-32-bit-to-the-64-bit-world/

Comment: @zapl do you mean I can't run it?

Comment: A Pixel 7 would give you the same no supported abi error as your emulator, a Samsung s23 on the other hand should run your app since it still supports armeabi-v7a